# How to call javascript functions in synchronization mode

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have below javascript code, I want then to call them in sync e.g 1,2,3,4.
Please suggest a solution. Can I use `async` and `await` keywords in it ?

```
function first(){
setTimeout(function(){
 console.log('1');
 },500)
}
function second(){
 console.log('2');
}

function third(){
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('3');
},502)
}

function four(){
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('4');
},501)
}

first();
second();
third();
four();
```

Comment: `setTimout` is by definition not synchronous, though... put the next function call at the end of the last function's timeout?

Comment: Check out [`async`/`await`](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use async/await, the only thing you need are promises (and support for async/await of course).

So given your example, the solution below should work.

```
function first() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('1');
    resolve();
  },500)
}

(async () => {
  await first();
})()
```

Comment: Hey there. Code only answers are usually frowned upon here (and for a good reason), after all, the core idea behind SO is to provide a learning resource for people interested in programming tackling specific issue. What it isn't is a free coding service

Comment: @Rawrplus I didn't realize I posted without some explaining, sorry for that.